# Java method overloading: method is undefined for the type

Tags: java, overloading

I am trying to have the command prompt ask the user for which day of the week it is, first by having them input the string for the day, then to have them input the integer for the day. I'm trying to overload methods 'dayName', but Eclipse keeps prompting me to assign a type to my first method. It says "The method dayName() is undefined for the type dayName. I thought making them static would help, but it does not in this case. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

```
 /**
     * 
     */
    package mytime;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    /**
     * @author Ashley
     *
     */
    public class DayOfWeek {

    static String day;
    static String weekday;
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    static String monday = "Mondays are a bummer.";
    static String tuesday = "At least it isn't Monday!";
    static String wednesday = "Getting there.";
    static String thursday = "Almost there.";
    static String friday = "TGIF";
    static String saturday = "Party!";
    static String sunday = "Oh no, school tomorrow!";
    static String errorDay = "Not a valid day of the week.";

    public static dayName(String day) {

        if (day.equals("Sunday")){
            weekday = sunday;
        } 
        else if (day.equals("Monday")){
            weekday = monday;
        }
        else if (day.equals("Tuesday")){ 
            weekday = tuesday;
        }
        else if (day.equals("Wednesday")){
            weekday = wednesday;
        }
        else if (day.equals("Thursday")){
            weekday = thursday;
        }
        else if (day.equals("Friday")){
            weekday = friday;
        }
        else if (day.equals("Saturday")){
            weekday = saturday;
        }
        else{
            weekday = errorDay;
        }
        return weekday;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Please enter day of the week:");
        day = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println(day);
        dayName weekday = new dayName();
        weekday.dayName();

        System.out.println(weekday);

        System.out.println("Please enter day of the week:");
        int day = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println(day);
        DayOfWeek(day);
        System.out.println(weekday);
    }
    public static dayName(int day){

        switch (day){
        case 1:
            weekday = sunday;  
            break;
        case 2:
            weekday = monday;  
            break;
        case 3:
            weekday = tuesday;  
            break;
        case 4:
            weekday = wednesday;  
            break;
        case 5:
            weekday = thursday;  
            break;
        case 6:
            weekday = friday;  
            break;
        case 7:
            weekday = saturday;  
            break;
        default:
            weekday = errorDay;
            break;
        }
        return weekday;

    }

}
```

Comment: `public static dayName(String day) {` There's no return type. Same for `public static dayName(int day){`

Comment: on a side note `dayName weekday = new dayName();` is wrong `dayName` is a function name not class name you have to do `DayOfWeekweekday = new DayOfWeek();`

Comment: `dayName weekday = new dayName();` You can initialized the method it should be the class named `DayOfWeek` remove all the static reference. with return valued as `String`

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass either `int` or `String` in method call

```
weekday.dayName();
```

change as

```
dayName(day);// because all are static method no need to create object
```

and also return type  is missing in method.

```
 public static dayName(String day)
```

change it to

```
 public static String dayName(String day)
```

same thing you need to do for other method  `public static dayName(int day)`.

so you need to change your logic as :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Please enter day of the week:");
    day = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println(day);
      weekday= dayName(day);
    System.out.println(weekday);

    System.out.println("Please enter day of the week:");
    int day1 = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println(day1);
    weekday=dayName(day1);
    System.out.println(weekday);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Several things might cause your problem.

## Short answer

1. use `String` return type for both `dayName()` methods.
2. do not use `dayName` objects in your main method, but use `String` instead

Replace:

```
day = input.nextLine();
System.out.println(day);
dayName weekday = new dayName();
weekday.dayName();
System.out.println(weekday);
```

By :

```
day = input.nextLine();
System.out.println(day);
String weekday = dayName(day);
System.out.println(weekday);
```

## Explanation

#### Undefined class `dayName`

Your code does not compile because you're trying to use a type (class) that you didn't define: `dayName`.

*Side note: class names should be capitalized in Java.*

In this piece of code:

```
dayName weekday = new dayName();
weekday.dayName();
```

You're assuming `dayName` is a class, but it does not exist. Maybe you wanted to use `DayOfWeek`?

#### Undefined method `dayName()`

> The method dayName() is undefined for the type dayName

The error message you're getting is because you are trying to use the method `dayName()` on the object `weekday` (of type `dayName`). This is because of your statement `weekday.dayName();`.

The thing is, you haven't defined such a method in that class (I don't even see the class `dayName` anyway, as stated in the first part).

#### No return type for `dayName(int)` and `dayName(String)`

The syntax you're using there is incorrect to declare a method:

```
public static dayName(String day) {
    // ...
}
```

because you don't provide any return type. If you don't need to return anything, specify the `void` return type like this:

```
public static void dayName(String day) {
    // ...
}
```

However, here you need to return a string, so put `String` instead of `void`.